# Why would Client/Server be faster across LAN than compared to run locally?

Tags: .net, performance, sockets

I have written a quick application to test some socket IO performance using .Net. I am sending messages to the server and receiving responses. I am using threads etc.

What I have found odd is when I run the both client and server locally it takes 15 secs to send and receive the 100 000 requests and responses. When I put the server on a different machine and run it across the LAN it takes only 6 seconds to perform the same workload.

When I use resource monitor I can see that when testing across the wire I am getting much more network IO throughput.

UPDATE:
My dev machine has ample resources. It has 8 cores, 8 gigs of memory etc and the program is stupidly simple.

Comment: Why not show us the source of your test client and server?

Comment: @alk it would be a bit of pain but I can do it. I thought it wasn't relevant seeing as it is the same code running. I am the one doing the testing and copying the binaries across. I thought the reason may be simple and making everyone look through code a waste of time.

Comment: My guess is contention on the socket.  Do you now have twice as much outgoing (both ways) and twice as much incoming on the same socket(s)?

Comment: @Blam I guessed the same. I ran it with Resource Monitor open and each side was reading/writing about 1 1200KB per second. So it was doing 2400KB per second. Maybe I did reach the limitation of the card.

Comment: Do local sockets end up with different defaults than non-local? For example, perhaps local doesn't set TCP_NODELAY while remote does?

Comment: Try adding a virutal card (Microsoft Loopback adapter) and use it for one side.